# AS3: Compare two (or more) nameless instances of the same class (on stage)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, instance, dynamically-generated

How to reference another instance of the same class? None of them have any names, as they are generated through code. A random amount of instances are generated each time. I need to compare them. Thanks.

This is the code I have on the timeline (which generates the instances).

```
var minLimit:uint = 1;
var maxLimit:uint = 10;
var range:uint = maxLimit - minLimit;
var p:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;

for (p; p <= maxLimit; p += 1)
{
    var myCell:Cell = new Cell();
    var xminLimit:uint = 100;
    var xmaxLimit:uint = 300;
    var xrange:uint = xmaxLimit - xminLimit;
    var xp:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*xrange) + xminLimit;
    addChild(myCell);
    myCell.x = xp
    myCell.y = xp
    myCell.scaleX = 3
    myCell.scaleY = 3        

}


var listOfCells:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int =0; i < (root as MovieClip).numChildren; i++)
{
    listOfCells.push((root as MovieClip).getChildAt(i));
}

trace(listOfCells)

var len:int = listOfCells.length;
for (var j:int =0; j < len; j++)
{
    trace(listOfCells[j].x);
}


trace("Cells on stage: " + Cell.count);
```

The game cenerates a random number of cells. In order to code so they sometimes go closer and inspect each other, I need to know how to compare them. Example, code I could put in the class - like: If this.x < OTHER(of the same class).x So I can compare two different instances within the same class.

Comment: What do you need to compare? Unclear what the problem is here.

Comment: The game cenerates a random number of cells. In order to code so they sometimes go closer and inspect each other, I need to know how to compare them.

Example, code I could put in the class - like:

If this.x < OTHER(of the same class).x

So I can compare two different instances within the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the cells and have them move towards each other if they are below 200px apart (for example):

```
var maxDistance: Number = 200;
var minDistance: Number = 20;

var len:int = listOfCells.length;
for (var j:int =0; j < len; j++)
{
    var cell: Cell = listOfCells[j];
    for(var k:int = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
        var cellToCompare = listOfCells[k];
        if(cellToCompare != cell) {
            var dx: Number = cellToCompare.x - cell.x;
            var dy: Number = cellToCompare.y - cell.y;
            var distance : Number = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            if(distance < maxDistance && distance > minDistance) {
                cell.x = cell.x + dx * 0.1;
                cell.y = cell.y + dy * 0.1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also to be sure the array only contains Cell instances, use the 'is' operator:

```
var listOfCells:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int =0; i < (root as MovieClip).numChildren; i++)
{
    var child: DisplayObject = (root as MovieClip).getChildAt(i);
    if(child is Cell) {
        listOfCells.push(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow. If I put this in the class actionscript file, how does it allow me to make them move closer to each other?

Comment: Hey @user3123633 I've updated with a basic approach for comparing the distance on moving together. Hope this sets you on your way.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for all the work you put in typing that code. I do get an error, however. "Can't convert 0 to Cell".

I assume I am supposed to add this on the timeline, and not the class itself?

Comment: Oops sorry I made a mistake. Hopefully only one! It should have been 'var cell: Cell = listOfCells[j];' not 'var cell: Cell = listOfCells[j].x;'. It can go alongside the code you posted.

Comment: Now I get another error :p "Can't convert flash.display::Shape@2c759fa9 to Cell"

Comment: A shape must have snuck into the array of cells. You can use 'is' to check the type. Have edited above.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're the best. Now, with the help of your example, I doubt I'll need any more outside help. THANK YOU!